# Service locator for a 2D game

Tags: c#, game

I'm currently developing a simple 2D game engine and I was just wondering, what are some things that I can do to improve my service locator class, at the moment it's very basic.

For example, should I be checking for null objects, if so, what exceptions should I throw?

Here's the code, thatnks in advance!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace GameEngine.Core
{
    public sealed class ServiceLocator
    {
        private static ServiceLocator instance;

        private Dictionary<Type, object> services;

        public ServiceLocator()
        {
            this.services = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
        }

        public void AddService(Type serviceType, object serviceObject)
        {
            this.services.Add(serviceType, serviceObject);
        }

        public void RemoveService(Type serviceType)
        {
            this.services.Remove(serviceType);
        }

        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            return this.services[serviceType];
        }

        public static ServiceLocator Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new ServiceLocator();
                }

                return instance;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this just for fun or if you want a simple one why not use the ServiceContainer class that's in .net already?

Comment: @CharlesNRice The ServiceContainer class seemed like a legit option, until I realized there's no Instance property.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are reinventing the wheel a bit too much.  If you need something simple then go with built in .net ones.  If you going to make a simple ServiceLocator then you should implement the [IServiceContainer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.iservicecontainer(v=vs.110).aspx) interface.

```
public sealed class ServiceLocator : IServiceContainer
```

This is a matter of preference but I usually set static instance property in a static constructor.  There isn't a lot of overhead in creating the object right away that we need to do locking or delayed creation when they access the property.

```
public static IServiceContainer Instance { get; }

static ServiceLocator()
{
    Instance = new ServiceLocator();
}
```

Now I would create two constructors one the default and one that takes a IServiceContainer

```
private readonly IServiceContainer _container;

public ServiceLocator() : this(new ValidationContext(string.Empty).ServiceContainer)
{
}

public ServiceLocator(IServiceContainer container)
{
     if (container == null)
     {
         throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(container));
     }
    _container = container;
}
```

I typically use the Servicecontainer from the ValidationContext class.  It's marked internal so we can not just new it up.  The difference between the [ServiceContainer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.servicecontainer(v=vs.110).aspx) class and the one from the ValidationContext is two fold.  One the ServiceContainer class implements [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) and two it caches the results from the [ServiceCreatorCallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.servicecreatorcallback(v=vs.110).aspx) delegate.   It would be up to you to decide which one of the ServiceContainers from .net you would prefer.

The rest of the methods I would just chain down to the container we set in the constructor

```
public object GetService(Type serviceType)
{
    return _container.GetService(serviceType);
}

public void AddService(Type serviceType, object serviceInstance)
{
    _container.AddService(serviceType, serviceInstance);
}

public void AddService(Type serviceType, object serviceInstance, bool promote)
{
    _container.AddService(serviceType, serviceInstance, promote);
}

public void AddService(Type serviceType, ServiceCreatorCallback callback)
{
    _container.AddService(serviceType, callback);
}

public void AddService(Type serviceType, ServiceCreatorCallback callback, bool promote)
{
    _container.AddService(serviceType, callback, promote);

}

public void RemoveService(Type serviceType)
{
    _container.RemoveService(serviceType);
}

public void RemoveService(Type serviceType, bool promote)
{
    _container.RemoveService(serviceType, promote);
}
```

This is a very simple Service Locator.   There are lots of very good dependency injection library out there but this will work if you only need a simple container.